# Get Value from a Lambda using Cloud Formation and check condition to branch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have attached the sample to give you some clarity of what i am trying to solve.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Project Service Catalog get lambda data

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment of the SageMaker
  
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: Project ID of the SageMaker

  SsmRoleLambdaArn:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/data-science/role-lambda/arn'
    Description: Arn to lookup Role of the Session using project id

Resource:
  IdentifyUserRole:
    Type: Custom::GetParam
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Ref SsmRoleLambdaArn
      pl_role: !Sub '${Environment}-sso-data-science-${ProjectId}-pl-role'
      ds_role: !Sub '${Environment}-sso-data-science-${ProjectId}-ds-role'

  KmsKey:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'Encryption for ${Environment}-${ProjectId}-${Prid}-${NotebookInstanceNameSuffix}'
      EnableKeyRotation: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref Environment
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner
        - Key: ProjectId
          Value: !Ref ProjectId
        - Key: PrincipalId
          Value: !Sub
            - "${RoleId}:${Prid}"
            - RoleId:
                Fn::If: [!Equals [!GetAtt IdentifyUserRole.value, true], !GetAtt PORoleId.value, !GetAtt DSRoleId.value]
```

I am getting error at the **IF** condition in the **PrincipalID** tag. Please help solve this condition with some sample templates. I can't use !GetAtt in the **Conditions** block as well because we are not supposed to use get attributes.

**Error Message - During stack validation**

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: Fn::If requires a list argument with the first element being a condition

Comment: The above template is just a sample one. Don't need to debug the parameter errors. Since i wanted solve the IF condition. I know some parameters are missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hard code the condition in the If like you are attempting:

```
 Fn::If: [!Equals [!GetAtt IdentifyUserRole.value, true], !GetAtt PORoleId.value, !GetAtt DSRoleId.value]
```

The first argument **must be condition** from `Conditions` section ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if)):

> reference to a condition in the **Conditions section**.

Subsequently, you can't construct  conditions based on `GetAtt` or any other resources from `Resources` section.

The same docs also write:

> You can only reference other conditions and values from the Parameters and Mappings sections of a template. For example, you can reference a value from an input parameter, but you **cannot reference the logical ID of a resource in a condition**.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up but any chance. I can do it in someother way because Get Att   needs to check the condition from a lambda and then proceed what is the best way?

Comment: @Arunachalam I updated the answer, but I don't think its possible. You could split your template, so that `IdentifyUserRole` is created in other template, and passed as a parameter to the lambda template.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for taking your time in answering the question. But for your information. After thinking through i moved all the **IF** condition part inside the ''IdentifyUserRole'' into the Lambda fuction and just used GetAtt over to get the Role ID. That is best possible thinking i had. as you said seperate template also would work i guess. Thanks cheers.